# How to install PlayOnLinux on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation, 16.04, playonlinux

I was trying to install `playonlinux` by terminal on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS but there is no commands for that version of Ubuntu (at least I didn't find them).

So I was wondering if somebody can help me.

Comment: What do you mean by "there is no commands"?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

At the *time of writing* this post, the application is provided by [noobslab.com](http://www.noobslab.com) for 16.04 version.

1. Add the repository by using the following in the terminal,

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/apps
   ```
2. Then update your package list,

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. And then installation,

   ```
   sudo apt-get install playonlinux
   ```

   This will install several libraries which are needed for `wine` as well as `playonlinux`. Installation of this is big >580 MB. It may take some time for installation.

Comment: Now there is no need for PPA, check with `apt show playonlinux`.

Answer (score 23):

You can simply run command

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install playonlinux
```

for installation. There is no need for PPA.

To update to the latest version, it needs to [download .deb file](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/download.html).

Comment: it will be not the latest version

Comment: You will need PPA for latest version..

Comment: @Ramesh-X When I installed it first time(in 16.04.1), I did without ppa and to upgrade it later(in 16.04.4) I just downloaded [.deb file](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/download.html). or you can follow the instruction given there to install playonlinux.