# Installing Wine, PlayOnLinux and League of Legends on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, wine, playonlinux

Can I please have some clear, simple instructions to get League of Legends running on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS as though freshly installed from a USB stick?

I assume this involves installing Wine and PlayOnLinux as all the guides I've read state this.

Several attempts have completely failed:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wine/wine-builds
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-devel
winecfg
```

and

```
sudo echo "foreign-i386 architecture" > /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine:i386
```

and

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.8 winetricks
```

all produced errors.

After having read

[How to install PlayOnLinux on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/770687/how-to-install-playonlinux-on-ubuntu-16-04)

and attempting

```
sudo apt-get install wine:i386
```

This messed everything up and I had to reinstall Ubuntu.

In PlayOnLinux - downloading League of Legends:

```
Error in main
glxinfo is not installed. Please install mesa-utils package
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install PlayOnLinux on Ubuntu 16.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/770687/how-to-install-playonlinux-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: @spomi: As you've never accepted an answer on this site before: If one of the answers *solved your problem*, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of its text, which means [Yes, this answer is the most useful of all](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Answer (score 1):

Go to a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type:

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

and that will solve your problem.

Comment: **Aegefel:** Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** Could you please review my [edits](http://askubuntu.com/posts/846006/revisions) and also review the [editing help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) to improve the readability of your answers in the future... **;-)**  Also avoid words like "Might", "Try", "Could"  in answers.  If you're unsure, it's a comment.  If you're sure, it's an answer!  **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

What work for me as patch 6.22 was changing settings of LoL launcher through PlayonLinux.

```
1.Install the most recent version of PlayonLinux and install the League of Legends. (Do not start game after installation)
```

2. Using PlayonLinux access the LoL game settings.

   3. In PlayonLinux change the default wine version using the "General" tab.From 1.9.2 LeagueofLegends5 to the latest stagging version. When i wrote this answer it was "1.9.22stagging" i install both x86 and x64 wine versions. (again this all done through the playonlinux settings)
3. Through playonLinux settings now access the "wine" tab and click on "configure wine" icon. There you will change the default windows version from Windows XP to Windows Vista. (all other don't seem to work at least not on my PC)

   5. Now using PlayonLinux start the LoL launcher (the screen will look weird, however, you should be able to see the League of legends logo on the top left, the percentage and download speed bar on the middle and the settings and minimize icons on the right.
4. This installation takes longer than when using windows.For me using Windows LoL installs in about 2.5 hrs. However, using Ubuntu it took 5 to 6 hours to install. During the installation it might seem like if the installation freezes or your installation stops and your download speed might even reduce to cero for a while but "PLEASE BE PATIENT"
5. Today is November 15, 2016 and i install LoL 6.22 and play.

   8.if there is any new patch i would try waiting for the new playonlinux stagging version of wine before removing or changing anything else.

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to be more up to date for me:

https://github.com/TheUnnamedDude/pol_league_of_legends

```
Download the script from: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TheUnnamedDude/pol_league_of_legends/master/league_of_legends.sh
Start PlayOnLinux.
Open the tools dropdown menu.
Select "Run a local script"
Select the script league of legends.sh
Follow the instructions and select your region.
```

When you're done with that you will get a shortcut named League of Legends, you should be able to launch it.

Comment: While a link is fine, please add the essential details here, as otherwise your answer won't be any good if that link doesn't work in the future.