# How to install playonlinux on Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: wine, 17.10, playonlinux

I want to install playonlinux on Ubuntu 17.10, I saw [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/770687/789148) question and its [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/778211/789148), But after `sudo apt-get install playonlinux` I am getting the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 playonlinux : Depends: curl
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken package
```

What can I do to fix this and get playonlinux installed?

**sudo apt-get update :**

```
arya@arya:~$ sudo apt-get update
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps/ubuntu artful InRelease [15.4 kB] 
Ign:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful InRelease                      
Hit:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                     
Get:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps/ubuntu artful/main i386 Packages [1,572 B]
Get:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps/ubuntu artful/main amd64 Packages [1,560 B]
Get:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps/ubuntu artful/main Translation-en [1,160 B]
Fetched 19.7 kB in 4s (4,087 B/s)               
Reading package lists... Done
```

**sudo apt-get upgarde :**

```
arya@arya:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

**apt policy playonlinux curl libcurl3 :**

```
arya@arya:~$ apt policy playonlinux curl libcurl3
playonlinux:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.2.12-1
  Version table:
     4.2.12-1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/multiverse amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/multiverse i386 Packages
curl:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 7.55.1-1ubuntu2
  Version table:
     7.55.1-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/main amd64 Packages
libcurl3:
  Installed: 7.55.1-1ubuntu2.3
  Candidate: 7.55.1-1ubuntu2.3
  Version table:
 *** 7.55.1-1ubuntu2.3 100
         100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     7.55.1-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Install `curl` as suggested?

Comment: I try to install it and it said this : 
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 curl : Depends: libcurl3 (= 7.55.1-1ubuntu2) but 7.55.1-1ubuntu2.3 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
@Rinzwind

Comment: Please also add the output of `apt policy playonlinux curl libcurl3` - and move that output from trying to install curl into the question as well. Thanks.

Comment: @AryaSadeghi you installed something else that is related to another version of Ubuntu. Can you tell us what that is? You cannot mix packages from different releases of Ubuntu - they are incompatible.

Comment: done... @ByteCommander

Comment: @Rinzwind Sorry but I don't know what is that, how can I know the wrong installed?

Comment: @AryaSadeghi it is the one with the *** so Byty has it correct ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an incompatible version of `libcurl3` installed on your system. Probably you had a PPA or other unofficial software source added at some point in the past which provided this.

The solution is to downgrade `libcurl3` to the correct version matching the other packages from the official repositories:

```
sudo apt install libcurl3=7.55.1-1ubuntu2
```

After that, you should be able to install `playonlinux`, as its dependency `curl` will no longer be blocked by a conflicting dependency version.