# Fonts in embedded wine

Tags: wine, fonts, menu, text

Glad that [notepad++](https://websiteforstudents.com/install-notepad-on-ubuntu-16-04-17-10-18-04-via-snap/) is now available in Ubuntu. **And no, I won't switch to NotepadQQ -- its features are not nearly as many as in Notepad++**

As far as I understand, it is run via sort of embedded Wine.

As always, fonts in menus are way too small in Wine applications, like this:

[image]

Usually, it is fixed via `winecfg`.

**But, how to fix fonts in an embedded wine?**

I have the following things in `~/snap/notepad-plus-plus`:

```
.
├── 140
│   └── notepad-plus-plus
│       ├── backup
│       ├── localization
│       ├── plugins
│       ├── themes
│       └── wine-platform
├── common
│   ├── .cache
│   │   ├── fontconfig
│   │   └── winetricks
│   ├── .config
│   │   ├── fontconfig
│   │   └── menus
│   ├── .local
│   │   └── share
│   └── .wine
│       ├── dosdevices
│       └── drive_c
└── current -> 140
```

`fontconfig` contains a file `fonts.conf` with the following content:

```
<fontconfig>
  <dir>/snap/notepad-plus-plus/140/wine-platform/usr/share/fonts</dir>
  <dir>/usr/local/share/fonts</dir>
  <dir>/usr/share/fonts</dir>
  <include ignore_missing="yes">conf.d</include>
  <cachedir prefix="xdg">fontconfig</cachedir>
  <cachedir>/home/NAME/.cache/fontconfig</cachedir>
</fontconfig>
```

**Any clues?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the alternatives to Notepad++ on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/313973/what-are-the-alternatives-to-notepad-on-ubuntu) (try NotepadQQ)

Comment: @N0rbert Nope. NotepadQQ compared to Notepad++ is like a crutch compared to a bazooka.

Comment: Thanks for asking this question: I just installed `notepadqq`... (also voted to leave open)

Answer (score 10):

You can run `winecfg` in npp snap like this `notepad-plus-plus.wine winecfg` then change your screen resolution `dpi`.

Comment: Running winecfg by itself and changing the dpi setting had no effect. Running it this way did. Thanks, this is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

## Use Playonlinux to configure wine

I do everything wine-related with playonlinux. It makes setup and maintenance around wine stuff much easier.

1. Install Playonlinux

   On Ubuntu 18.04 just do

   ```
   sudo apt install playonlinux
   ```

   On Ubuntu 16.04 follow the following steps from this [guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/770687/how-to-install-playonlinux-on-ubuntu-16-04)

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/apps
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install playonlinux
   ```
2. Download the Notepad++ **32bit** version from the offical [download-page](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v7.6.html).
3. Start Playonlinux. Open the start-menu and begin typing `playonlinux` then click it.
4. Running Playonlinux: Click the `Install` icon. In the dialog, click the search box in Playonlinux and write `Notepad` select the top entry and click `Install`. [image: Playonlinux install dialog]
5. There are two dialogs to click `next`, then a dialog which ask if you want to download or use a allready downloaded installer - this one has aa magnifying glas icon on the left. Click the maginfying glas entry. [image: installer dialog] Browse to your downloaded `npp.7.6.Installer.exe` file and click `Ok`.

This will install notepad++ with known good wine settings.
[image: First start with Notepad++]

Answer (score 0):

Just run this command (on a single line):

```
WINEPREFIX=~/snap/notepad-plus-plus/common/.wine winecfg
```

then, select the "graphics" tab, and set the screen resolution to a reasonable value (I have 150 DPI).

S. Nokkia